# How do I use multiple conditions in thymleaf - "If statement"

Tags: if-statement, thymeleaf, or-operator

I am trying to display a delete button only for the person who post a comment and for the ADMIN, however
when I try to hide it using an if statment or sec:authorize there is an error parsing the template.
I tried to do two separete buttons using each if condition separately and it worked fine, however when I combine them using OR there is a mistake.

This is what I have wrote so far.
// the HTML

```
            <a th:if="${c.email}==${namePrincipal} or hasRole('ADMIN')" href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" style="background-color: #8db8e0; margin-left: 200px;">Delete</a>
```

The error message:
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/show-comments.html]")

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression: "${c.email}==${namePrincipal} or hasRole('ADMIN')" (template: "show-comments" - line 34, col 20)

Comment: Hey I think I was mixing thymeleaf security with the normal thymeleaf syntax. hasRole('ADMIN') did work with sec:authorize, but not with the th:if. What I  implement at the end is creating a "hasRoleAdmin" attribute in the controler and using  it like this:th:if="${hasRoleAdmin} or ${c.email}==${namePrincipal}". Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To give the permission based on roles ,`sec:authorize` is used

```
       <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                    <div th:if="${#authentication.principal.username} eq ${c.getEmail()}">


            <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" style="background-color: #8db8e0; margin-left: 200px;">Delete</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
```